# Is there any way to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 through it's ISO?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 14.04

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and wanted to upgrade using the 14.04 LTS ISO.

Any way?

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: If you burn the ISO image and boot with the DVD created, you'll be able to perform the upgrade. If you have an USB external drive with virtual CD/DVD feature (some enclosures like Zalman ZM-VE300 allow that), you'll be able to boot on the ISO image mounted as if it was a real CD/DVD. You can also create an USB boot disk from the ISO with "Startup Disk Creator" which is included in Ubuntu. If you want to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 without waiting July, you can also use this command line in Terminal: update-manager -d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution 1: Burning the ISO of Ubuntu 14.04 and booting the DVD

If you burn the ISO image and boot with the DVD created, you'll be able to perform the upgrade. You just have to select the option for upgrading your current installation of Ubuntu 12.04. Your data will be kept and the setup process will try to reinstall the packages installed (even external ones), if possible (of course), at the end of the install process.

It is even possible to upgrade from a 32-bit edition of Ubuntu 12.04 to a 64-bit edition of Ubuntu 14.04 that way. Of course, in that case, no previous package can be reinstalled...

Of course, it is not booting from the ISO itself (see Solution 2 below).

### Solution 2: Using an external disk drive with Virtual CD/DVD feature

If you have an USB external drive with virtual CD/DVD feature (some enclosures like Zalman ZM-VE300 allow that), you'll be able to boot on the ISO image mounted as if it was a real CD/DVD.

If you have an external disk drive, but no Virtual CD/DVD feature built-in, you might be interested by [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), [MultiSystem](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/) or else.

### Solution 3: Creating an USB boot disk from the ISO with "Startup Disk Creator"

You can create an USB boot disk from the ISO with "Startup Disk Creator" which is included in Ubuntu by default. Just type "Startup Disk Creator" in the Dash.

### Solution 4: Upgrading via Internet [ISO not used in this case]

If you want to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 without waiting July 2014, you can also use this command line in Terminal:

```
update-manager -d
```

However, the ISO won't be used in this case. Everything will directly be downloaded from Ubuntu repositories.

### Note

Don't forget to backup your data before performing any upgrade. It's always better to have a backup even if you don't have to use it than having no backup when you really need one ;-)!

Comment: The upgrade option seems disabled. What to do?

Comment: I've never faced that issue before. I've even tried to reproduce your problem in a VM, but the upgrade option is available there too... Here is the screenshot of what you should normally see: [link](http://storage6.static.itmages.com/i/14/0601/h_1401646485_9475046_6619f685f2.png)

Comment: If you still encounter the same problem (upgrade option disabled), I think that you should submit a bug report via Launchpad...

Comment: While upgrading from 32 to 64 bits, how can I make a list of packages that I need to install manually?

Comment: @gshilin: I don't know if there is a way to do that while upgrading. It is possible to make a list of installed packages before upgrading, with Synaptic (File -> Save selections) or by using the command "dpkg --get-selections > installed-software". You then have to make a lot of clean up in the list generated to keep only the packages you wish. After upgrade, you can read the selections from Synaptic (File -> Read Selections) or by using "dpkg --set-selections < installed-software" then the command "dselect". Pay attention to architecture and changes in package names!

Comment: @gshilin: Making a list of the main packages or meta-packages manually (separated by spaces) and using a command like "sudo apt-get install main-package1 main-package2 main-packagex meta-package1 meta-package-2 meta-package3" might be a better and cleaner solution in your case. Personally, I prefer reinstalling the packages I'm sure I need manually, then I install the ones I've "forgotten" when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Even you can upgrade without ISO image, so need to delete 12.04 and reinstall 14.04.
so need to download all application,application data again in 14.04.

follow the following steps:-

First things first: make sure that you are fully up-to-date. Double check by opening the Update Manager application from the dash and installing all updates listed.

When that’s done, open the Dash again and launch the Terminal application. When it opens click inside the window and type the following command carefully:

```
 update-manager -d
```

Hit the enter key and, if prompted, enter your user password.

The Update Manager application will open after a few seconds with a prompt to upgrade. Click to begin the process.

NOTE:- Your system should to connected to internet.
       If using laptop Keep in AC mode.

Comment: But I wanted to install 14.04 on another PC too. That's why wished to download the ISO and minimize Internet usage and time.

Comment: If you just download 14.04 ISO and burn it, you'll be able to upgrade your other PC too. Boot on the DVD created and select the upgrade option. Your data will be kept and the setup process will try to reinstall the packages installed (even external ones), if possible (of course), at the end of the setup process. I've even made an upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit to Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit that way. Of course, in that last case, no previous package could be reinstalled...

Comment: @Ashutosh Kale: "sudo" is not needed for "update-manager -d".